# Remove newline character just every N lines

Tags: text-processing

Processing text, I need to remove the newline character every two lines.

Sample text:

```
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too
```

Desired output:

```
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

I tried a `while` loop, but a while loop is bad practice. Is it possible to do it using `tr` or any other command?

Comment: The title says "every N lines", but in the question and example it's "every 2 lines".  Most of the answers work only for N=2.  Are you looking for something that works for all N?

Comment: That's the key. Everybody answered for 2 lines but I would need to use N=3 o r N=4

Answer (score 25):

`paste` (also a standard POSIX simple utility like `tr`) is your tool for that.

Assuming you want those newline characters replaced with a space instead of just *removed* as in your sample:

```
paste -d ' ' - - < file
```

Or:

```
paste -sd ' \n' file
```

Replace `' '` with `'\0'` if you do indeed want them removed.

To replace 2 out of 3:

```
paste -sd '  \n' file
```

1 out of 3, starting with the second:

```
paste -sd '\n \n' file
```

And so on.

Another good thing with `paste` is that it won't leave a line non-terminated. For instance, if you remove *every* newline in a file (as with `tr -d '\n' < file` or `tr '\n' ' ' < file`), you end up with no line at all as lines need to be terminated with a newline character. So it's generally better to use `paste` instead for that (as in `paste -sd '\0' file` or `paste -sd ' ' file`) which will add that trailing newline character necessary to have valid text.

Answer (score 12):

With modern **GNU sed**

```
sed -rz 's/\n([^\n]*\n)/ \1/g' sample.text
```

And **awk**

```
awk '{getline line2;print $0, line2}' sample.text
```

Comment: That `sed` approach means slurping the whole file in memory (provided it doesn't contain NUL bytes) and do some expensive regexp substitution. I can't see the benefit over the standard `sed 'N;s/\n/ /'` approach.

Answer (score 6):

Use `sed` for this as shown below:

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp $ cat a
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too

SHW@SHW:/tmp $ sed 'N;s/\n/ /' a -i

SHW@SHW:/tmp $ cat a
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

Answer (score 6):

This is actually extremely simple in vim. To join every line use the `J` command, then use the `%norm` command to do apply it to every line simultaneously. For example

```
:%norm J<CR>
```

(Just in case you are unfamiliar with vim, `<CR>` just means enter)

This even works to join an arbitrary number of lines. For example, to join every ten lines would be

```
:%norm 9J<CR>
```

If you are uncomfortable with vim, and you would prefer to use it as a command line tool, rather than an interactive text editor, you could do:

```
vim myfile -c '%norm J' -c 'wq'
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Had to get an account only to say I love your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `xargs`:

```
$ < txt xargs -d '\n' -n 2 echo
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

where

```
$ cat txt
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too
```

Although, this solution is quite excessive because an `echo` process is executed for each line ... Thus, besides toy examples, a solution based on awk/sed or similar should be preferred.

Comment: Depending on your `echo` implementation, you'll also have problems with backslash characters or some lines that start with `-` (like `--help` or `-nene` with GNU `echo`). Also note that `-d` is a GNU extension.

Comment: To avoid issues with `echo`, you can use this: `< txt xargs -d '\n' -n 2 printf -- '%s %s\n'`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?" ":"\n")}' sample.txt
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

This prints out each line, `$0`, followed by either a space or a newline depending on whether the line number, `NR`, is odd or even.

The expression `NR%2?" ":"\n"` is a ternary statement.  The expression `NR%2` evaluates to true (nonzero) if the row number is odd.  In the case, the ternary expression returns a space.  If it evaluates to false (zero), then the newline is returned.

#### Alternative

As suggested by Costas in the comments:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2?" ":RS)}1' sample.txt
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

Here, the ternary statement `NR%2?" ":RS` is used to return either a space or the input record separator (`RS`, default=newline).  This value is assigned to the output record separator, `ORS`.  The `1` at the end of the command is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-record.

Comment: You can still save 3 characters: the `()` parentheses and the space after `printf` ;)

Comment: Ternary? Oh! `'NR%2{printf("%s ",$0);next}1'`

Comment: With [maxschlepzig's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304393/89144) and ternary statement: `'{ORS=(NR%2?" ":RS)}1'`

Comment: @Costas I like that.  Answer updated with `ORS` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generic solution, replace `5` with number of lines required

```bsh
$ # eof to ensure last line has newline ending
$ seq 16 | perl -pe 's/\n/ / if ++$i%5 && !eof'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16

$ # or just use pr
$ seq 16 | pr -5ats' '
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk '{c="\n"} NR%2 {c=" "} { printf("%s%s", $0, c) } ' txt
```

It produces:

```
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

where:

```
$ cat txt
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too
```

The `awk` actions are executed for each line, the special variable `$0` references the current line, `NR` is the current line number (starting at 1). The second action is guarded by the expression `NR%2`, which is the modulo operation. Thus, `c=" "` is only executed if `NR%2` is true, i.e. for odd line numbers.

The `awk` syntax is C like, but some elements are optional in some contexts - e.g. semicolons.

Comment: Your `c` variable is `ORS`: `'NR%2{ORS=" "}1;{ORS=RS}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed`:

```
$ cat text
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too
this is line one
and this is line two
the third and the
fourth must be pasted too

$ ed text <<'END_ED'
g/./s/$/ /\
j
w text.new
END_ED
164
164

$ cat text.new
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
this is line one and this is line two
the third and the fourth must be pasted too
```

The `ed` editing commands will, for each line (`g` applies a set of editing commands to every line matching the given regular expression), add a space character to the end and join it with the next line. Then it writes the resulting text to a file called `text.new`.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby.

I assume each block of `n` lines are to be joined. Suppose `n = 3`, the input file is `'infile'` and the results are to be written to the file `'outfile'`.

*Construct a file*

```
Ruby -e "File.write 'infile', <<_
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
> Line 4
> Line 5
> Line 6
> Line 7
> _"
```

*Confirm the contents of the file*

```
ruby -e "p File.read 'infile'"
  # "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\nLine 6\nLine 7\n"
```

*Remove newlines and write to file*

```
ruby -e "File.write 'outfile', File.readlines('infile').
  each_with_index { |line,i| line.chomp! unless (i+1)%3==0 }"
```

*Confirm contents*

```
ruby -e "puts File.read 'outfile'"
  # ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3\n", "Line 4", "Line 5", "Line 6\n", "Line 7"]
```

Comment: Good one.  In theory, `ruby` is off-topic on U&L.  But, since you are using it from the command line with `ruby -e`, that makes it on-topic enough.